# second scanf to recognize keyword to exit iteration of integers? C

Tags: c, scanf

Trying to accept integers separated by either spaces or lines until the user types the keyword "end" at which time the program will look for an operator (+ - * /) to perform the action on the entered integers.

I keep getting the "comparison between pointer and integer" warning when compiling which makes sense but I'm not sure the correct way to fix it.  There is a note where the problem in the code is.

Can someone please assist me with the correct syntax for this second scanf to exit the iteration and move on to the operator input.

Thanks for any help!
PS: yes I know there are easier ways to write the program but I'm very new to C and am using this as another chance to practice.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void) {
   int iarray[100];
   char stop[100];
   int c = 0;
   char action[100];
   while (scanf("%d", &iarray[c]) == 1) {
         if (scanf("%s", stop) == "end")      // the issue is here
            break;
         else
             continue;
      c++;
   }
   if (c == 0) {
      printf("error");
      return 1;
   }
   scanf("%s", action);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you reduce your posted code to a minimal sample, that reproduces that warning please?

Comment: `scanf` returns an `int`, not a `const char*`.

Comment: I included the full code (not much after all) so that it would be easy to copy and paste into a compiler and see what I was trying to do... in the past when I posted partial people requested full... can't make everyone happy and I'd rather give too much, notate the part in question, than not give enough information.
Got it all sorted now though but thank you very much for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first issue: Try to read to string and then translate the string to integer by using `sscanf`, if it is not equal to "end". (compare by `strcmp` not by `==`).

second issue: when you read numbers, you never reach to c++. the continue make it skip it.

for example, you can do it like this:

```
char temp[100]
while (scanf("%s", temp) == 1) {
     if (0 == strcmp(temp,"end")) // return 0 when both equal... 
        break;
     else{
        if( 1 == sscanf(temp,"%d",&iarray[c]))
           c++; //number successfully read, increment counter. 
        else
           break; //not end nor number...  
     }
}
```

Comment: that's perfect I was thinking about it in reverse... also I didn't know about sscanf() that is exactly what I was needing.  if I had +15 I'd hook you up with an ^... I'll come back when I do.  Much appreciated.